# Symfony2 FOS Comment Bundle error

Tags: symfony, bundle, foscommentbundle

I?m having problems with my FOSCommentBundle. I've set up my bundle and it worked for a couple of days, but today it's not working. I'm crushing my head and cant get to a solution.

The problem is that the fos_comment_script.src = '/web/js/35a8e64_comments_1.js' doesn't exist, i cant access it, so no threads are added and nothing is displayed. 
I'm not receiving any errors, nothing, everything looks fine but nothing is happening.
I am using async.twig.html and the javascript that is generated on my page looks like this

```
// thread id
var fos_comment_thread_id = '309';

// api base url to use for initial requests
var fos_comment_thread_api_base_url = '/web/api/threads';

// Snippet for asynchronously loading the comments
(function() {
var fos_comment_script = document.createElement('script');
fos_comment_script.async = true;
fos_comment_script.src = '/web/js/35a8e64_comments_1.js';
fos_comment_script.type = 'text/javascript';

(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(fos_comment_script);
})();
```

Thank you vary much in advance.

Comment: can you find the file manually or doesn't it exist?

Comment: the file is there under the vendor/path/to/comment.js, but the '/web/js/35a8e64_comments_1.js' doesent exsit.

Comment: You probably forgot to run `php ./app/console assetic:dump --env=dev` after the cache was cleared or something. Please for more information take a look at the asset_management part of [the symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I lost a couple of hours on this :(, such a simple solution. Thank you vary much for yore help, joy showers my  being :).

Comment: can you please accept the answer :) Glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably forgot to run php `./app/console assetic:dump --env=dev` after the cache was cleared or something. Please for more information take a look at the asset_management part of [the symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)

Comment: This didn't helped, but adding `assetic:      bundles: [  "FOSCommentBundle" ]` 
as in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/0CUeXtuJgQU and calling the command helped. May be I missed it.